# AttributeError for exception subprocess.TimeoutExpired

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, exception

I have a python3 code that uses subprocess exception [TimeoutExpired](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.SubprocessError), but I need this to run on python2. My code is a simple try and except subprocess.TimeoutExpired but it is only available on python3. I apologise for the simplicity of the question. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout feature is available on Python 2.x via the `subprocess32` backport of the 3.2+ subprocess module. You can get the module [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess32/)